# Can dockerized containers truly run on any Linux node?

Tags: linux, docker

Can docker images created with one version of linux (say ubuntu) be run without problem on ANY other version of Linux? i.e. CentOS?

So far I have not had problems in my testing but I am a new to this.

I'd like to know if there are any specific use cases that might make a Docker container non-functional on a host node due to the host's Linux version.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

> Can docker images created with one version of linux (say ubuntu) be run without problem on ANY other version of Linux? i.e. CentOS?

Older kernels may not have the necessary namespace support for Docker to operate correctly, although at this point Docker seems to run fine on the current releases of most common distributions.

Obviously the host must be the appropriate architecture for whatever you're running in the container. E.g., you can't run an ARM container on an x86_64 host.

If you are running tools that are tighly coupled to a particular kernel version, you may run into problems if your host kernel is substantially newer or older than what the tools expect.  E.g., you have a tool that wants to use `ipset`, but `ipset` support is not available in your host kernel.

Comment: There are other tools with kernel components that have potential for compatibility issues; for instance, sysdig didn't play nicely with Docker until quite recently.

Answer (score 0):

You're only likely to have an issue if you have code that relies on a kernel feature that isn't present on another host. This is certainly possible, but unusual in everyday usage.